# spring mvc update operation

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I've got two tables: Dish and Ingredient (one-to-one relationship). In each table there are fields like `last_modified_by`, `creation_time` which are not required by users to update.

In the controller I send the object to the jsp page by, which works fine.

```
uiModel.addAttribute("dish", dish);
```

At the jsp page side, I use jsp form tags, setting modelAttribute as `dish`. I only allow users to modify some useful information like `dishName`. There comes my question:
how can I only modify some properties of `dish` in model, and then send it back to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it could a bug of Spring 3.2.x, otherwise it's designed to behave in this way.

Adding an annotation `@sessionAttribute` on the controller is the graceful way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to create a dto representing only the fields that should be accessible, you then send this to and from the form.

```
public DishDto {
  public getName(){};
  public setName(){};
  private String name;
}
```

This strategy also allows you to mix two different entities/tables within one dto/form.